# Unable to delete aws/efs/automatic-backup-vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-backup

I am currently logged in as the root user. I am trying to delete the following EFS backup vault:

aws/efs/automatic-backup-vault

When I do I receive the following error:

Insufficient privileges to perform this action. Please consult with the account administrator for necessary permissions.

When I try and go to the policies to give myself the ability to do this, enter the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }]
}
```

The json enter shares the following error:

> This policy JSON contains 3 errors that require attention starting on
> line 7 See the individual validation errors in the JSON editor for
> more information.

Additionally, I used AWS-Nuke to try and clear everything out, and this little bit of configuration remained. Previously I was getting:

> The specified policy cannot be added to the vault due to cross-account
> sharing restrictions. Amend the policy or the vault's settings, then
> retry request.

I am unsure of what to do next or if the second error is still relevant here as the JSON is being denied. I also was having an error around Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to Fix the Policy in Backup Vault in two steps.
1 - Change the AWS Principal: "*" to "arn:aws:iam::[AWSAccountID]:root"
2 - After that, you can change the policy: Deny to Allow.

Is this a necessary because you can't change the effect with single account actions with a principal "*".

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with deleting this vault; AWS would not let me change the backup vault access policy [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77143047/3474146).

Note that `aws/efs/automatic-backup-vault` is an AWS-managed backup vault that gets created automatically when you toggle `Automatic backups: Enabled` on a given EFS file system.

To disable these backups themselves, take a look at the recovery points present in this vault to determine which EFS file systems are targeted (it should be all EFS file systems with the `aws:elasticfilesystem:default-backup: enabled` tag) and modify those EFS file systems to disable `Automatic backup`.